# Is it possible connect Rails 4 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2008, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I couldn't connect my database Sql Server 2008 to Rails 4. The Sql Server adapter is for active record 3.2 and Rails 4 use active record 4.0, so someone can help me?

Comment: Ok, I understand. So if I need to connect an Sql Server database I have to use active record 3.2 right ?

Comment: That's correct (so rails 3.2) or use an unstable version or wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL server active record adapter is not yet ready for Rails 4. You can use it by targeting the [github version](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) however there are still [issues](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues?labels=4.x&state=open) you need to be aware of and it may be unstable in the near future until a release is formally made.

You could look at the adapter and fix some of these issues and send a pull-request?